# Why does the IRS refer to the "Certification of U.S. Residency for Tax Treaty Purposes" as a "form" (Form 6166)?

Tags: word-choice

Why does the [U.S. Internal Revenue Service (IRS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_Revenue_Service) refer to the [Certification of U.S. Residency for Tax Treaty Purposes](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/certification-of-us-residency-for-tax-treaty-purposes) as a *form* (Form 6166)?

http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/form:

> a printed document with blank spaces for information to be inserted.

which that doesn't seem to match the description of a certificate.

---

Form 6166:

[image]

([image source](https://www.washingtondcapostille.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/IRS-Form-6166-Apostille-Example.jpg))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form is a document which has a predefined structure (or "form") These letters have defined structure.  They always say the same thing "This person is a resident of the USA for tax purposes".  They always use the same standard headed paper.

Moreover, in older use a "form" is a "standardised legal document"

Finally, calling this a form gives consistent naming.  In the IRS system everything is a "form".  (Compare this to the UNIX system where "everything is a file")

Comment: Very interesting, thanks!

Comment: As to "certification", it's completing the form that does the certifying. If government issues a form that certifies something, that might be called a certificate.

Comment: For my money, as it were, the last paragraph is the only answer to this question.